# How to purposely throw an Error in the shell script

Tags: shell, jenkins

I want to write a script which throws an error when the status of url is not equal to 200. As this script has to be executed on Jenkins so it should make the build fail.This is the script which i have written -

```
STATUS=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}' http://google.com)
  if [ $STATUS -eq 200 ]; then
    echo "URL is working fine"
    break
  else
    echo"URL is not working"
    cd 123
 fi
```

The above script works correctly but i need something else instead of -cd 123 syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> but i need something else instead of -cd 123 syntax

You could say:

```
exit 42
```

instead.  This would make the script exit with a non-zero exit code that should be picked up by Jenkins.

`help exit` tells:

```
exit: exit [n]
    Exit the shell.

    Exits the shell with a status of N.  If N is omitted, the exit status
    is that of the last command executed.
```

Comment: @kapilGarg Just like that; you could even say `exit 1`.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest solution is to execute curl and use the `-f` option. It makes curl exit with non-zero exit code when web server returns something else than 200 OK.

You could also make your life easier by setting the `-e` option for shell. This causes shell to abort immediately when a command returns an error (= non-zero exit code).

So, your example above would be reduced to:

```
set -e
curl -sf -o /dev/null http://google.com
echo "URL is working fine"
```

Comment: @user797963 Not really that awesome if you need to fake a curl call just to throw an error :D